# ASP.NET Theme reference broken on pages in sub folders

Tags: asp.net, themes

I have a page that derives from a master page.  The page has a theme defined and displays properly.  If I move the page to a sub folder in the web, the theme is no longer used.  I see the following generated in the  tag:

```
<link href="http://localhost:50815/MyWeb/../App_Themes/GreenBlue/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

So the problem is the /../ Why is this being generated?  How do I fix it?

One more thing, the href above is being generated by setting the page's Theme in the markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/DashboardMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeFile="DataSourceSetup.aspx.cs" Inherits="DataSourceSetup" Theme="GreenBlue" %>
```

I'm not manually adding the `<link href=...`  It is being gnerated, and incorrectly at that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/App_Themes/GreenBlue/Stylesheet.css");

the page will then substitute the right ../ based on where you are

Comment: I understand that this will give me the path, but my problem is with generated markup from setting the theme at the page level.  I was hoping this would just work, but maybe from what you are saying here I should set the theme manually in codebehind?  - Thanks for the help!